# Which algorithm is used to hash the password here?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, security, hash-function

I'm using the Webmatrix.WebData.Security library to control the login/register functionality of my site. The CreateUserAndAccount() method hashes the password the user gives and stores it within the table webpages_Membership. I'm having trouble understanding how the method hashes it. 
Could somebody help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the SimpleMembershipProvider, you can view the source on CodePlex.

The actual code is in the `HashPassword` method of [System.Web.Helpers.Crypto](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1962da8fcfe4#src/System.Web.Helpers/Crypto.cs)